# Regex for searching a inputed sentence but including special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, json, special-characters

So straight to the point. I am currently making a college project that consists on search a JSON file for specific words/sentences according to 2 types of research: Restrict which means case sensitive and Lexical which means case insensitive
And return the occurrencies in bold format

Currently i'm using this regex as a search method

```
regex = new RegExp(inputSearch, "g"); //case sensistive
```

and

```
regex = new RegExp(inputSearch, "gi"); //case insensitive
```

"inputSearch" beeing the variable that contains the sentence/word that0s supposed to be found, my problem is that i need to include special characters such as these ".:,;!?-_" so if, for example, i search for "How are you?" it would return all the occurrencies of that sentence including the "?"

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `regex = new RegExp(inputSearch.replace(/(\W)/g, "\\$1"), "gi");`

Comment: @AvinashRaj awesome , really good solution, I was just wondering how to achieve

Comment: If you're looking only for exact words and not using any regex features, then you should rather use `indexOf`. Case insensitivity can be achieved by making both text and word lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape all the special characters present in your variable with `string.replace` function.

```
var regex = new RegExp(inputSearch.replace(/(\W)/g, "\\$1"), "gi");
```